# Use .htaccess file to check folder for file and redirect if not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to use .htaccess files so that if someone visits an old URL on our new website such as website.com/oldpage.asp .htaccess first checks to see if website.com/oldsite/oldpage.asp is on our server. And if no file is there redirect them to old.website.com/oldpage.asp where a copy of our old website exists.

For some reason only the .htaccess file in the /oldsite/ folder is executing.

Here is my .htaccess file for my site root which checks if the file exists on the new site and if not redirects to /oldsite/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oldsite/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Then in /oldsite/ its supposed to check if the file again exists, and if not redirect again.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.website.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 .htaccess for this.

Have this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/oldsite/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ oldsite/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then remove `/oldsite/.htaccess` and test this after clearing your browser cache.